# Configuration failed: FileNotFoundException but not found in log

Tags: configuration, filenotfoundexception

On a Windows Server 2012, I configured as a domain controller and installed SQL Server, then tried to install SharePoint, but I get a FileNotFoundException at the end of configuration:

[image]

Strange thing: The linked file does not contain the string "FileNotFoundException", nor does any of the many log files in the same folder (searched through Windows Explorer).

Where can I see the problem?
The log file is huge and seems to contains only `INF` lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting your Central Admin web app from IIS (after snapshotting your VM or backing it up from IIS using AppCmd - not that necessary though if it's a fresh install) and running the config wizard again.

Comment: Thanks! For readers who might not know, here is how to delete the Central Admin web app: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67227/how-to-remove-the-central-admin-web-app