# How to remove the Central Admin web app?

Tags: central-administration, web-application

How to remove the Central Admin web app from IIS?

I am using SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2012.

---

I know I can [remove an app](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262820%28v=office.14%29.aspx) with the `SharePoint 2010 Management Shell` by issuing:

```
Remove-SPWebApplication –identity http://sitename -Confirm
```

but when I replace `http://sitename` with the URL to the Central Admin web app `http://myserver:46828` I am told: `Cannot find an SPWebApplication object with Name, Id, or Url: http://myserver:46828`.

Comment: Why would you want to remove *THAT*??  That's a weird question.

Comment: @BGM: I was told to do this, if I understood well it is the first step described in this answer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/61066/14701

Comment: Ah, so you are trying to uninstall Sharepoint Server so you can reinstall it afresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to [remove Central Administration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11771636/286244), you can use this script:

```
Write-Host "Removing central administrations:"
$applications = Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | where-object {$_.IsAdministrationWebApplication -eq $true }
if($applications -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "No central administrations found."
    return
}
foreach($application in $applications)
{
    Write-Host "$($application.Url)"

    # for central administration web application Remove-SPWebApplication cmdlet requests confiramtion
    # even if parameter '-Confirm:$false' is used

    # Remove-SPWebApplication $application -DeleteIISSite -RemoveContentDatabases -Confirm:$false 
    Write-Host "`t removing iis site"
    $application.UnprovisionGlobally($true);

    Write-Host "`t removing databases"
    foreach ($contentDb in $application.ContentDatabases)
    {
        $contentDb.Unprovision();
    }

    $application.Delete();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I get `An expression was expected after '('.` for the final line. Adding a semicolon does not solve the problem either. Also, `WriteFuncInfo`  has only 9 results on Google, and returns `CommandNotFoundException`.

Comment: Then replace them with Write-Host.

Comment: `Write-Host` solves the second problem. To solve the first problem, I just removed the function. Benny, I edit your solution to reflect what worked for me, OK?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Great! Thanks for the team work! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove or add Central Administration from/to IIS on specific hosts, just use

```
psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -unprovision
```

or

```
psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -provision
```

on these hosts.